# Yii2Assets/yii2-pdfjs doesn't work with enablePrettyUrl enabled

Tags: yii2

I have installed **Yii2Assets/yii2-pdfjs**, it was working fine until I have enabled enablePrettyUrl in the urlManager.

I have found the problem:
In the file

```
yii2-pdfjs/views/viewer.php
```

If I replace the default url

```
$url = Url::to(['/pdfjs/','file'=>Url::to($urlFile)]);
```

by

```
$url = Url::to('/pdfjs/?file='.$urlFile);
```

It works

```
$urlFile="/link_to_my_pdf.pdf"
```

the $url generated is: `mydomain.com/pdfjs/?file=/link_to_my_pdf.pdf`

So my question is: is there a solution to add a trailing / in **Url::to** or is there another solution?

Comment: You have  several $url ... what do you mean with "$url = Url::to(['/pdfjs/','file'=>Url::to($url)]);  "  show me the content of the $url  actula and expetced ..

Comment: @scaisEdge I have added the details of urls

Comment: but in your sample you seems that you don't need  the urlManager result (the full yii2 relative paths) for the file param value   but simply a string that content the filename with a leading slash .. if this is what you need  you should not use the ulrHelper but simply use a string concat ..

Comment: What's default action action of `PdfjsController` ? You may need to `url_encode("/link_to_my_pdf.pdf")` in second case, because first case is automatically encoded by Url helper. Also give exact value of `$urlFile` e.g. there may be invalid character. BTW - you dont need trailing slash `/`.